# DataTables ajax request - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I'm using DataTables with AJAX endpoint and when i'm initiating datatable on site I keep getting an error saying "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". I've tryed to make this code work but with no effect

json result from request

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "28",
            "id_transakcji": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "kod": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "id_kodu": "xxx",
            "email": "xxxxxxxxxx@o2.pl",
            "status": "W Toku",
            "xxyy": "10",
            "xxyya": "xxxxxxx",
            "xxaa": "xxxxxxx",
            "xxx": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "data_utworzenia": "2019-05-01 20:51:31"
        },
        {
            ...
```

config of that datatable

```
var mytable = jQuery('#Transactions').dataTable( {
                ajax: {
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {action:'get_transactions'},
                    dataSrc: ''
                }
                columns: [
                    {"data": "id"},
                    {"data": "id_transakcji"},
                    {"data": "kod"},
                    {"data": "id_kodu"},
                    {"data": "email"},
                    {"data": "status"},
                    {"data": "xxyy"},
                    {"data": "xxyya"},
                    {"data": "xxaa"},
                    {"data": "xxx"},
                    {"data": "data_utworzenia"}
                ]
            } );
```

html for table

```
 <table id="Transactions" class="display" style="width:100%">  
    <thead>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>ID Transakcji</th>
      <th>Kod</th>
      <th>ID Kodu</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>status</th>
      <th>xxyy</th>
      <th>xxyya</th>
      <th>xxaa</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>data_utworzenia</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>ID Transakcji</th>
      <th>Kod</th>
      <th>ID Kodu</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>status</th>
      <th>xxyy</th>
      <th>xxyya</th>
      <th>xxaa</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>data_utworzenia</th>

   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thank You

Wiktor

Comment: Ok sorry my bad... i haven't hooked action for logged in user. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

add `"pageLength": 10,` for `datatables()`

```
var mytable = jQuery('#Transactions').dataTable( {
               "pageLength": 10, //10 just an example
                ajax: {
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {action:'get_transactions'},
                    dataSrc: ''
                }
                columns: [
                    {"data": "id"},
                    {"data": "id_transakcji"},
                    {"data": "kod"},
                    {"data": "id_kodu"},
                    {"data": "email"},
                    {"data": "status"},
                    {"data": "xxyy"},
                    {"data": "xxyya"},
                    {"data": "xxaa"},
                    {"data": "xxx"},
                    {"data": "data_utworzenia"}
                ]
} );
```